# No new updates in almost a month?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I have been running the software updater every week. Since the middle of December, there have been no new updates. It keeps saying that the software on my computer is up to date.

Is this just because of Christmas or something? Normally there are lots of updates every week. What is going wrong and how can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version ?

Comment: @Serg I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: That should be fine then. I manually ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` . The only packages that are going to be upgraded for me at least are the following:`astyle flashplugin-installer hedgewars-data libplank-common libplank1
  numix-icon-theme plank screen unity-tweak-tool yelp-xsl zsh zsh-common
  zsh-doc` If you have none of those, then no need to worry I suppose. Besides it's holiday season. Developers have holidays too :)

Comment: @serg So you suspect that it has to do with the holidays. Nothing wrong with my Software Updater?

Comment: That's my personal guess, nothing more , nothing less. Wait some time, maybe a week or so. If still no updates coming automatically, we can continue to trouble shoot. Also remember that you can update manually with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` .